# Angular : pass optional data within route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-routing

I'm using **angular 5** , I ve a long routing file :

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'registration',
        component: RegistrationComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'synthese',
            component: SyntheseComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'queue',
            component: QueueComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'queue-modal',
                component: QueueModalComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'confirm',
                component: ConfirmComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
...
```

And i want to pass data within the "**registration**" path .

As i was told , i need to write it like this :  `path: 'registration/:mydata'`,

and after that subscribe to data of **ActivatedRoute**

The problem that i'm not always passing data , it s only in some cases.

**How may i make it with minimum of impact ??**

Comment: maybe you can pass a null value and when you use Activatetour check if it's null ?

Comment: You can create two routes `registration/:mydata` and `registration`

Comment: Kinda looks looks like the example in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#hero-feature-routing-requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querystring parameters (AKA [queryParams](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/query_params)) instead of route parameters. You do not need to define query params in the route.

Here is an example of a relative href:

```
registration/?mydata=123
```

This is how you can define `queryParams` for a `routerLink`:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['registration']" [queryParams]="{ mydata: 123 }">Go to Registration</a>
```

This is how you can read that param value:

```js
myValue: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.myValue = params['mydata'];
  });
}
```